# How do I use a custom-custom song?

Tags: geometry-dash

### Analogy:

In [The Impossible Game](http://store.steampowered.com/app/251630/?snr=1_7_7_151_150_1), its level editor allows you to choose your own song by simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or clicking the "Open Audio" button.

In [osu!](http://osu.ppy.sh), you can simply drag any .mp4 file into the editor and you can start editing a beatmap (or set of beatmaps) for it.

---

#### Question:

Is it possible to do that in [geometry-dash](/questions/tagged/geometry-dash)? ([Store link](http://store.steampowered.com/app/322170/?snr=1_7_7_151_150_1))

The closest thing I've found to that is this:
[image: "Custom" Song Selection]
Which basically restricts me to anything on [newgrounds.com](http://www.newgrounds.com/audio/).

Can I use a custom-custom song (one *not* from [Newgrounds](http://newgrounds.com/audio))? If so, how?
**Basically, any work-arounds?**
Obviously on a map that I definitely plan on not uploading, but for my personal use.

Comment: What does the Create Lines button do, and what comes up when you click the Help button?

Comment: @ShadowZ. the **Create Lines** button is only creating guide lines and setting the song's offset. Please refer to [this screenshot](http://steamcommunity.com/id/aytimothy/screenshot/39741578458569277).

Comment: Hmm, i see. Does the help button bring you to anything to help along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: Download any song in-game. Remember the song ID. It should be displayed in the "Saved" folder.

2: Get your .mp3 file.

3: If you are playing on a Windows computer, go to "C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\GeometryDash" and replace the music file with the song ID you remember with your .mp3 file.

4: If you are playing on a Mac computer, go to "~/Library/Caches/" and replace the music file with the song ID you remember with your .mp3 file.

5. Use that song in-game that you changed.
6. Have fun!

(Note: This is not universal and it will only affect your song. No one else will hear the same .mp3 file as you do. Other than what I've described, there is no other way to get a custom-custom song)

Comment: I think you may have got the point. I'll confirm and mark if accurate.

Answer (score 0):

On [SteamCommunity](http://steamcommunity.com/app/322170/discussions/0/620702121656952622) I've found this question:

> **Any chances of non-newgrounds music for editor in future?**
>   Being able to use our own music in the editor would be great. And if for some reason you wouldn't like custom music in the in-game public user levels, then just don't allow songs with custom music to be submitted publicly. We can share them outside the game if we have to.

And that's not the only one asking this. So I think it's pretty obvious you can't (for now).

Comment: Do you think you could suggest how it could be done? (ie. Reskin files?, *but though it's simple to copy over and replace a downloaded song's file with a song of your own desire, are there any extra steps? ie. Change any verification like MD5s stored in another metadata file?*)

Comment: It could be simple to replace the downloaded song, but it will be probably coded or encrypted. I don't know how to do this, sorry.

Comment: Downloaded songs are not encrypted In any way whatsoever.

Answer (score -1):

***Since Newsgrouds isnt going to be your opions, There are other options you can do.***

1: Download a custom music from a level, such as Cataclysm uses At Speed Of Light. You can download it using the download button, As this will give you a warning when you play the game, that you have no song downloaded.

2: Go to your level, open your custom music folder, (which is where it is on your picture) Open Saved and that will lists all the music that you downloaded from the level. And your completely done!

Otherwise not, If your talking about music not USING Newsgrounds music, such as iTunes. I'm sorry, but that wont be compatible with Geometry Dash yet, since they are just using Newsgrounds. RobTop Developers may add it in the mean while. Maybe wait for Geometry Dash 2.0, a great update :D

Hopefully this has fixed your problems! :D Have a great day building your levels!

Comment: Right. I'll be testing it. Also, do you not realise that "where it is on your picture" is [Newgrounds](http://newgrounds.com/audio)? *Try fixing your answer, or deleting it if it's completely wrong.* Do you have any working proof?

Comment: Update: @GeometryDashPlayer Your answer is **wrong**. You are giving steps for using [Newgrounds](http://newgrounds.com/audio). If you haven't read the question, it is about **anything *but* than Newgrounds**.